# Two Way Binding Path=. Will Not Save

Tags: c#, wpf

```
public DataContext
{
  public ObserverableCollection<int> Integers;
}

<DataGrid ItemsSource={Binding Integers, Mode=TwoWay}>
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=., UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Shows all the numbers just fine. But, if you modify something, the values never save. You can enter 999999 and the collection will never update that index corresponding to the row.

If I made a silly wrapper class called IntegerModel and give a integer called "Value" a get and set, then change Binding Path=. to Binding Path=Value, it works fine.

[This site](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a44a3690-e191-460a-9736-747e02269cc9/wpf-datagrid-twoway-binding-whats-wrong?forum=wpf%20%22This%20site) mentions it in an answer, but doesn't know why. I'd like to know why myself. If its a INotifyPropertyChanged event issue, then why does it work with a normal getter and setter wrapper?

Comment: As I understand it, binding can affect only _members_ of a bounding source, not the value of the binding source itself. That you can even bind one-way to the value of a binding source at all is an exception to the rule, provided for convenience. But to update the source would require creating a whole new binding every time the value changed, which the binding system is clearly not designed to do. (Not posting this as an answer because it's speculation, not a definitive explanation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm basing this on what I know about the .NET Framework's internals. It is an educated guess.

The "silly wrapper class" you mention "boxes" your integers, which are value types, into object types. This permits you to add an implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged`, which is necessary because the binding is not to the `ObservableCollection`, it is instead one binding to each of the elements in the `ObservableCollection`.  It gives the binding system the hooks it needs to modify your integers when your changes trigger a source update.

It is slower than operations would be as pure value types, but, if you're operating at user interface speeds, it shouldn't be a discernible problem.